# Launch intent with some sound file

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android application containing more than 60 buttons. Each button responds to an Activity. Each Activity contains a sound file sourced from a raw file, a TextView and an image. Is there any way that I can use Intent parameters for each button?

For example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("soundfile", "FirstKeyValue");
myIntent.putExtra("image", "SecondKeyValue");
myIntent.putExtra("text", "ThirdKeyValue");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: 60 buttons do not sound like a good design. Why do you use a ListView ?

Comment: can you give a link about this?

Comment: sure, http://developer.android.com/

Comment: check this for listview http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Make  method let suppose

```
 public void sendMysong(String songname,String imgUrl,String text)
    {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("soundfile",songname);
    myIntent.putExtra("image",imgUrl);
    myIntent.putExtra("text",text);
    }
```

//  Now in receiving Activity receive intent data

```
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {

             String fname=extras.get("soundfile");

        int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

             MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sixty button in single layout is not a good design pattern, you must use either grid or List view.

Using List View
http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html

Using Grid View
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

As far as the current problem is concerned
You can create a generalized Function as given below

```
public boolean startActivityFoo(String value1,String value2,String value3)
{
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("soundfile",value1);
myIntent.putExtra("image",value2);
myIntent.putExtra("text",value3);
startActivity(myIntent);
}
```